# Slots of typ formula

Tags: r, oop, r-s4

I am trying to use a slot of type formula. But formula isn't a basic datatype. What can I do to create a slot to store objects like formula. Or is it intentional to prohibit storing general S3 objects as slots? If it's intentional to use slots of type S4, how do I turn the S3 class formula into S4 class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work for me:

```
setClass("form", representation(f="formula"))
myForm <- new("form",f=y~x)
myForm
An object of class "form"
Slot "f":
y ~ x

class(myForm@f)
[1] "formula"
```

Comment: Thax, this structure was also my first trail, and I got an error "cannot use object of class “formula” in new():  class “Myclass” does not extend that class". But your code works fine. But in general, is there a way to use other S4 classes as slot types?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it helps if you use named arguments in your call to `new`. S4 classes as slots are supported.

```
setClass(Class = "B", representation = representation(var1 = "character"))
setClass(Class = "A", representation = representation(var1 = "B"))
b<-new("B",var1="b")
a<-new("A",var1=b)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to use a mechanism like

```
 class B{
    int varb=0;
 }

 class A{
     B classvar;
     A(B var) classvar=var;
 }


 b=new B();
 a=new A(b);
```

Currently I do it in this way

```
  setClass(Class = "A",
     representation = representation(var1 = "list")
     )

  setClass(Class = "B",
     representation = representation(var1 = "character")
     )
  b<-new("B","b")
  a<-new("A",list(b))
```

to save S4 object like a class variable.

Comment: You do not separate arguments from function names with spaces.